# Setting minimal number of data that goes into one cluster

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have dataset of 20.000 rows. Al rows contain textual data.
I want to use K-Means so that I can check how many clusters do I have.
Optimal number of clusters that I get is 120 (based on  silhouette_score).

This is my code:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans    
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_samples, silhouette_score

for i in range(2, 500):
    
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = i, max_iter = 1500, init = 'k-means++', random_state = None)
    kmeans.fit(vec_matrix_pca)
    inertias.append(kmeans.inertia_)
    
    cluster_labels = kmeans.fit_predict(vec_matrix_pca)
    
    silhouette_avg = silhouette_score(vec_matrix_pca, cluster_labels)
        
    print("Number of clusters", i, "Silhouette Score:", round(silhouette_avg, 4))
```

The problem that I have is that some clusters have more than 500 datapoints, and some less than 5.
So my question is, is there a way to set minimal size of each cluster based on the number of datapoints.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5366/clustering-k-means-or-otherwise-with-a-minimum-cluster-size-constraint) question is similar enough and the answers there can help you.

Comment: There is no answer on my question on the link that you provided. FYI, im getting totally different results when I use GMM

Comment: Really? You want to set a minimal number of data points that go into a cluster, right?? From my link, there is a [publication](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/tr-2000-65.pdf) in one of the answers, doing **exactly** that! Either, you didn't read the thread very carefully (already its title is very close to yours), or I got your question completely wrong. The answer by @Tasos also mentions this algorithm! So, if there was no answer in the link, but already 2 people understood it this way, you might have to rephrase your question for us to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to keep the number of clusters to 120 and also have a minimum number of points on each of them with the built-in functionality of KMeans in scikit-learn.

You can do one of the following:

- Use another algorithm such as [DBSCAN](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html), where you can define the `min_samples` to whatever you want, but no way to set the number of clusters.
- You can do a custom post-model solution on KMeans, where you iterate through the clusters and if the number of points are less than X, you calculate the distance of those to each centroid of the rest of the clusters and assign them there.
- Use another library called [k-means-constrained](https://pypi.org/project/k-means-constrained/) (not affiliated with it)

For the last one, it works like that:

```
from k_means_constrained import KMeansConstrained
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0], [4, 2], [4, 4], [4, 0]])

clf = KMeansConstrained(
     n_clusters=2,
     size_min=2,
     size_max=5,
     random_state=0
 )
clf.fit_predict(X)
```

This will create 2 clusters with points between 2 and 5.

Comment: How can I check performance of this model, is there a Silhouette score?

Comment: Same metrics as any other clustering model.

Comment: I am getting this error: ValueError: The product of size_max and n_clusters must be larger than or equal the number of samples (X)


And my data has shape (10000, 2)

Comment: do you know what can be the issue?